# Unable to select a row using setSelection

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

To select a row, I have been using:

```
    $('EndcoderDetails').setSelection('EncoderDetails_jqg48',false);
```

where `EncoderDetails_jqg48` is the row `id`, but it is not working for me in `jqGrid 4.12.0`

Has the method changed?

Comment: You should provide the demo which can be used to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You wrapped `EncoderDetails_jqg48` with two single quote('). This is a problem. Another problem is your selector. It should be `#EndcoderDetails`. Change your code like following. Hope this will help you.

```
 $("#EndcoderDetails").setSelection (EncoderDetails_jqg48, true);
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/azim101/x6Lcv67c/